# Java. Properties.

Tags: java

Добрый вечер, господа. Помогите победить непонятку с класом [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).
В качестве файла конфигурациооного я использую некий xml файл.
Примерно такого содержания.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment/>
<entry key="sound">off</entry>
</properties>
```

Далее делаем так:

```
properties = new Properties();
try {
fos = new FileOutputStream("ru/marketsoft/reminder/property.xml");
fis = new FileInputStream("ru/marketsoft/reminder/property.xml");
properties.load(fis);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Получаем параметры, меняем из, короче всё ок, ровно до момента сохранения. можете толково ответить как нужно сохранять? При выходе из приложения, или сразу после установки. Пробовал и в xml (результат пустой файл) и как текст (данные двоятся).
Может кто покажет рабочий пример?

---

Короче вот так сделал (без XML пока, но это только пощупать).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * User: dimka3210
 * Date: 10.03.13
 * Time: 10:20
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("property.xml");
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fileInputStream);
            properties.setProperty("sound", "on");
            properties.store(fileOutputStream, "");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidPropertiesFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как оно у вас вообще работало? Судя по примеру вашего кода, файл property.xml затирался ещё до начала чтения, соответственно, вы ничего оттуда прочитать в принципе не могли. Кроме того, если вы грузите данные из XML, то делать это нужно методом `loadFromXML()`. Вот рабочий код:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("ru/marketsoft/reminder/property.xml");
        properties.loadFromXML(fis);
        properties.setProperty("test", "test");
        fos = new FileOutputStream("ru/marketsoft/reminder/property.xml");
        properties.storeToXML(fos, "no comment");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }
```

Comment: За минуту до вашего ответа сделал сам. За помощь естественно спасибо!
Можно закрывать.

Answer (score 2):

> Можно ли записывать значения int? Я пытался - ругается, только Стринги
>   принимает -_-
>
> Что делать?..

Properties на то и Properties, что для пар ключ-значение используются только ключи и значения класса String. [документация Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Как альтернатива используются что-то из реализации интерфейса Map [интерфейс Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) - обычно какой-нибудь HashMap или HashTable